# (DDR4/RAM) Writing speed more faster than reading speed

Tags: memory, performance, intel-core-i7, overclocking

This is giving me a headache. As I know, all RAM modules are a bit faster while reading instead of writing due it's nature. My only and last (I think valid) theory: a bad DDR4 timings (calculated by my motherboard btw).

There are some benchmarks (userbenchmark reveals some heavy performance waste at single-core also):

AIDA64 benchmark: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw8Tx.png

UserBenchmark: https://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/22076207

And there is my timmings:

```
tCL: 13
tRCD: 18
tRP: 18

tRAS: 33


tRC:50
tWR: 10
tCWL: 13
tRRD_S: 2

tRRD_L: 4
tWTR_S: 2
tWRT_L: 8
tCCD_S: 2
tCCD_L: 4
tRFC: 596
tRTP: 9
tFAW: 8
tCMD: 1


tREFI: 12711
tREFIx9: 110
tXP: 8
tXPDLL: 29
tPRPDEN: 2
tRDPDEN: 17
tWRPDEN: 28
tCPDED: 4
tAONPD: 11
tCKE: 1
RFR Delay: 14


tXSDLL: 1024
tXS Offset: 5
tZQOper: 512
tMOD: 24


tRDRD_sg: 6
tRDRD_dg: 4
tRDRD_dr: 6
tRDRD_dd: 7
tRDWR_sg: 9
tRDWR_dg: 9
tRDWR_dr: 9
tRDWR_dd: 10
tWRWR_sg: 6
rWRWR_dg: 4
tWRWR_dr: 7
tWRWR_dd: 7
tWRRD_sg: 26
tWRRD_dg: 20
tWRRD_dr: 6
tWRRD_dd: 7
```

I'll really appreciate any help with this!

EDIT: 
I forgot to say. tCL, tRCD, tRP and tRAS are manually selected!

Comment: I'm unable to identify a question here... What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: RAM speeds aren't correct. Write speeds are better than read speeds. And there's a major performance loss while reading in single core (24GB/s), while I can write at 48.4GB/s. And in multicore the write speeds lows to 44GB/s, but read speeds now reach a reasonable values like 43.2GB/s. No sense speeds... Please check my userbenchmark result and compare with other: https://ram.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/735311/Crucial-BLS16G4D30AESCM16FE-2x16GB

Comment: I forgot to say. Copy speeds gets low values for some reason at single and multicore also.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1117593/notto) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/1117605/notto). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)